# Missing standard message body reader providers in my jar

Tags: java, jersey, client

I must missing something for two days now...

I have a simple jar app which use a jersey client jar.
When I run my main class from Eclipse or from mvn exec everything goes fine.

When I build my jar then run it with a java -jar, I get :

> com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body reader for Java class java.lang.String, and Java type class java.lang.String, and MIME media type application/json was not found

i.e. all standard Java types body readers providers are missing from my client's providers list.

I declare in the client's pom.xml dependencies to :

- jersey-client
- jersey-core
- jersey-json
- jersey-server
- jackson-mapper-asl
- jackson-core-asl
- jersey-multipart

The only way for making my app working is to declare StringProvider class in my client's config...

```
config.getClasses().add(StringProvider.class);
```

But this provider decleration must only be necessary for custom beans? Standard bean providers are accessible by default? Aren't they?

Answer (score 8):

I'm finding this almost a year after it was posted, but turns out that my problem was due to merging everything into a single jar using shade. Adding a couple more transformers seems to have fixed things up. My shade plugin conf now looks like so:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.sandwormz.jettycore.NotezWebsocketMain</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.sandwormz.jettycore.NotezWebsocketMain</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                This is required if we want anything build on top of this
                                to
                                compile without security errors.
                                <artifact>*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>**/*.MF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>**/*.DSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Man!! I had wasted complete 1 day before I saw this. You are the savior!! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you bundling all the classes in a single jar (including the classes from jersey modules)? If so, then this looks like you are missing some META-INF files or you merged it in such a way that one file of the same name in one module overwrote a file with the same name from some other module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Martin. I firt package my client with all jersey deps, in a client.jar. I've used maven shade to ensure the META-INF was correctly built. Then I package my final app with a dependency to my client jar. I'll check all my META-INF files anyway

Comment: StringProvider is registered in jersey-core module in META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader. See if it is present in that file in your client.jar.

Comment: Well... In fact the META-INF rep of my client.jar is empty as I build this jar "without dependencies", like a library. But in my app.jar, which use the client, the META-INF contains all providers classes (from jersey-json and jersey-core). You think that the problem is that the providers are not registered in the client.jar itself?