# Java @POST Webservice 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have read through all the other posts, but seem to be getting this issue not sure why:

JAVA:

```
@Path("/acct")
public class MyService
{

    @Path("/create")
    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public MyClass myClass( AccountForm aform ) throws exception
    {       
       System.out.println("MYtest");
    }
}
```

POSTER CLIENT:
[image]

I see this in the logs:

SEVERE: A message body reader for Java type, class AccountForm, and MIME media type, application/xml;charset=UTF-8, was not found

Comment: Show us the code of `AccountForm` and how you configured XML mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know for sure but in the header tab of your poster tool add a header called accept and set it to application/xml.

Comment: SEVERE: A message body reader for Java type, class AccountForm, and MIME media type, application/xml;charset=UTF-8, was not found

Comment: Try this link it should solve your problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594707/jersey-exception-severe-a-message-body-reader-for-java-class/17777247#17777247