# Angular JS POST request map to DTO in REST Services

Tags: angularjs, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I am new to Angular JS and REST services and just trying hello world.

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-helloworld-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
             <param-value>com.ipocc.service</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

REST SERVICE CLASS

```
@Path("/UserManager")
public class UserManagerService {

    @POST
    @Path("/validate")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON } )
    public Response responseMsg1(final User user) {
        System.out.println("POST :" + user + " " + user.getUserName() + " "  + user.getPassword());
        return Response.status(200).entity("output").build();
    }
}
```

DTO

```
@XmlRootElement
public class User {
     @XmlElement public String email;
     @XmlElement public String name;
     @XmlElement public String username;
     //GETTER-SETTER 
}
```

ANGULAR JS FILE

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', []);
validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.submitForm = function() {

            var update_path = "http://localhost:8080/IPOCCService/rest/UserManager/validate";
            var data1 = angular.toJson($scope.user);
            alert(data1);            
            $http({
                  url: update_path, 
                  method: "POST",
                  data:  data1,
                  headers : {
                         "Content-Type" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         "Accept" : "application/json"
                   }
             }).
             success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 alert("success");
             }).
             error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                 alert("failure");
             });

    };
});
```

ERROR I AM FACING

```
SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class com.ipocc.service.dto.User, and Java type class com.ipocc.service.dto.User, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found.
The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
```

I want to achieve the when I call http post request from Angular JS, it should get map to user object but I am getting error above. If I keep parameter as String then I am getting data as `email:"a@a.com",name: "j",username: "j"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with jersey, but it looks like you are missing the `jersey-json` dependency to parse the received JSON data. - [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594707/jersey-exception-severe-a-message-body-reader-for-java-class)

Comment: I am having jersey-json dependency

Answer (score 0):

if it helps someone...

I am sorry for making blunder mistake. in my dependencies, jar version was mismatched and now its working after making changes like below in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```