# Error converting JSON to object via jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I've created DynamicWeb project (not maven) in eclipse with Target server Tomcat 7.

In location '\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib' I placed jars:
jersey-json-1.19.jar
jersey-bundle-1.19.jar
jersey-core-1.19.jar

in web.xml I have:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Pojo:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "input")
public class InputOb {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Rest resource:

```
@Path("/add")
public class AddOb {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)   
    public Response add(InputOb input) {
        ....        
    }   
}
```

When I try to call it, I am getting:

> SEVERE: A message body reader for Java class datatypes.InputOb, and
>   Java type class datatypes.InputOb, and MIME media type
>   application/json was not found.

Comment: This same issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594707/jersey-exception-severe-a-message-body-reader-for-java-class), have you tried this?

Comment: to try what ? every thing described there is was implemented

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your dependencies through pom.xml and use maven to run. Maybe something goes wrong with the jars.

Comment: as stated I am not using maven