# POST Java POJO to Neo4j Unmanaged Extension

Tags: neo4j

I have created one RESTful unmanaged extension and deployed under plugin directory of Neo4j 3.1.2. My REST method is accepting custom POJO with POST method. Whenever I am trying to hit my extension, I get below response:

> MIME media type application/json was not found. 
>       The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
>       com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
>       com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
>       com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
>       com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
>       com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
>       com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
>       com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
>       com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8594810/6835358) you can fix this issue by adding `jersey-json` as a maven dependency.

That is: adding the below lines to your `POM.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno, its working now. I was missing @XmlRootElement annotation.

Comment: Hi @AmitG You are welcome! Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/360570) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Otherwise, if your own solution has solved the problem, I suggest to you answer your own question and accept your answer when possible.